# Two CPU vs dual core?

Tags: cpu, cpu-speed, intel-pentium, quad-core, dual-core

Are two single-core CPUs (in a two-socket system) equivalent to a single dual-core processor?

Can we also say two single-core CPUs have half as much processing power as a single quad-core system?

My above understanding is based on Puget's [Dual Processor vs Dual Core](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Dual-Processor-vs-Dual-Core-23/) article.

Comment: Close to half of what?

Comment: i mean may not be exact half but near to that

Comment: The article you link to is extremely out of date,  i would argue, it was never accurate to begin with.  If a computer has two single core processors, provided the multi-core processor is of the same generation and architecutre as the single core processors, then performance of both will actually be about equal to one another.

Comment: Also make sure the cache sizes are comparable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### This is probably not the answer you want to hear, but, *it depends*:

- Adding a socket mean adding more total memory bandwidth.¹
- Adding a socket means some memory will be slower (E.g. if memory connected to CPU0 is accessed from CPU1)
- Adding a socket for a whole new CPU die also means adding full sized cache.
- And of course it also means doubling the number of cores.

#### What it also means is that:

- Caches are usually not shared. (a single socket dual core CPU is likely to share hits in its L2 or L3 cache). Processes migrating from core to core which end up on the wrong CPU might suffer.

The same principles hold for 2 dual-core CPUs vs 2 quad-core CPUs. Memory bandwidth used to be more of a problem in the past, so two dual core CPUs would have been preferable of one quad-core CPU if you do things like large matrix multiplication.²

#### Where does that leave us?

Well, for an average desktop user, the performance difference is not big enough to worry about. Price or PCIe lanes are another thing. If you want more PCIe lanes, then dual socket systems are your thing. If money is important, stick to single socket (and a CPU with double the number of cores).

---

¹ At least these days, when the memory controller is on the CPU or APU die. Back in ye ages of yore, it was on the northbridge.

² Common in HPC with matrices significantly bigger than any cache.

Comment: By the way: The memory bandwidth differences and whatnot is called NUMA – Non-uniform Memory Access.

Comment: I had NUMA explained around 2010, but my understanding of it is not good enough to add it to a post without fear of missing something.